# Why jobs and system config were lost when run an image commited from a running jenkins container?

Tags: jenkins, docker

I started a jenkins container from the official jenkins image and added some plugins like git. Also, I made some basic configurations like authentication settings and user registration, then I added a jenkins job and it worked quite well in the running jenkins container.
Question is when I commited this jenkins container as a new version of jenkins image and re-ran the new image, everything was lost: no plugins added, no user registered, no jenkins job created.
Does anyone can help me to make a new jenkins image with all my configurations added? Thank you all.

Regards,
yuliang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to backup your data before rerun jenkins image:

```
docker cp jenkins-dv:/var/jenkins_home /tmp/jenkins-backup
```

also you can check this very helpful tutoriel **[DOCKER & JENKINS: DATA THAT PERSISTS](https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/docker-jenkins-data-persists)** explain *HOST MOUNTED VOLUMES and DATA VOLUME CONTAINERS*

Comment: Hi Rubeus, thanks for your answer.  I backer the /var/jenkins_home and restored it when run the old image, it worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Dockerfile of Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/67f1189b45ba454acc72eb6117107c6f08c2663a/Dockerfile) defines a volume for its home directory:

```
# Jenkins home directory is a volume, so configuration and build history 
# can be persisted and survive image upgrades
VOLUME /var/jenkins_home
```

Per default Docker manages this volume on a per container base. If you would like to use same data as in your old image/container version you have mainly two options:

Give volume a name at run

```
docker run -v jenkinshome:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

or map it to a volume on host system:

```
docker run -v /some/dir/jenkinshome:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

This way data will persist image upgrades. You can read more about managing data at [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/).